# Html5 Data attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4, custom-data-attribute

I am using theme that i bought for my rails project and author of the theme uses html5 data attributes to background image and the code looks like this

```
   <section class="jumbotron full-height relative" data-pages-bg-image="assets/images/banner_1.jpg" data-bg-overlay="black" data-overlay-opacity="0.5">
```

I found a resource on how to use data attributes with rails but its not really working for me. Here is the link that i found
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag

how would i convert the above code to work in rails(I'm using erb as a template engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same markup, however, you need to use RoR's helpers to get the image's url - you can use [image_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path):

```
   <section class="jumbotron full-height relative"
      data-pages-bg-image="<%= image_path('images/banner_1.jpg') %>"
      data-bg-overlay="black"
      data-overlay-opacity="0.5">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work assuming you have the correct asset path:

```
image_tag("assets/images/banner_1.jpg", class: "jumbotron full-height relative" data-bg-overlay: "black", data-overlay-opacity: '0.5')
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, to the answers below, if you really want to convert it to erb template you could write it like this:

```
<%= content_tag(:section, "", class: "jumbotron full-height relative", "data-pages-bg-image" => "assets/images/banner_1.jpg", "data-bg-overlay" => "black", "data-overlay-opacity" => "0.5") %>
```